# torch.backends.mps.is_available() is False. How can I change it?

Tags: macos, pytorch, conda, torch

I want to use mps, but my computer doesn't work.
I think the problem is macOS version. I don't know why my version is 10.16.

I installed anaconda, and version is `conda 23.3.1`

```
Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr 20 2023, 13:59:00) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Python 3.10.11 (main, Apr 20 2023, 13:59:00) [Clang 14.0.6 ] on darwin
Type "help",
"copyright"
"credits"
>›> import platform
"license" for more information.
>>> platform.platform()
'macOS- 10. 16-×86_64-i386-64bit'
>>> import torch
>>> torch.backends.mps.is_built()
True
>>> torch.backends.mps.is_available()
False
```

This is my MAC Info screen capture.

[image: MAC info]

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/metal/pytorch/), the Metal PyTorch backend is only available with Apple Silicon or AMD GPUs. The system shown in OP (Intel Iris) does not satisfy that requirement.